# image as a button but without the button image

Tags: html, button, layer

This is a simple show hide layer script when clikling on an image
I want to click in the image instead of the button, and don't want to have an ugly button image morf or want to add a css style to cover the button

I tried assigning the image variable but it did not work

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<button onclick="toggle();"><img src="image.gif" /></button>////---- works
<image onclick="toggle();"><img src="image.gif" /></image>//// ----doesnt

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

or would it be easier to assign a behavior to the image

Answer (score 2):

In the following line of code -

```
 <image onclick="toggle();"><img src="image.gif" /></image>
```

You are assigning a click handler to an `<image>` tag, which is not there in `HTML` as far as i know, hence it won't be rendered by the browser. While the `<img>` which will be rendered does not have a click event handler..

Simply change it to

```
<img src="image.gif" onclick="toggle();"/>
```

For this to work, you should have a function named `toggle()` as follows

```
function toggle(){
  $("#div1").fadeToggle(1000);
}
```

or change your js to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeToggle(1000);
 });
});
```

In this case you don't need the `toggle()` function and`onclick="toggle();"` handler inside the `<img>`